# Firebase check if account is disabled

Tags: swift, swift3, firebase-authentication

I am currently trying to create a function that automatically detects if an account has been disabled or not.

By this, I mean that I want the user to be logged out automatically, and not have the permission to do anything.

I know the stuff about permissions are done in firebase security & rules. However, I have no idea on how to disallow activity from disabled accounts. I am only familiar with the auth.uid and variables.

How should I proceed if I want to do this?

I have played with the idea of re-authenticating the user for each form it proceeds to, but I quickly figured out that this would be unnecessary use of data.

Or is this the way to go?

Answer (score 1):

One of the way is use of authentication. You need to re-authenticate the firebase user:

```
user?.reauthenticateWithCredential(credential) { error in
  if let error = error {
    // An error happened.
  } else {
    // User re-authenticated.
  }
}
```

You get FIRAuthErrorCodeUserDisabled error if account is disabled.
Run this in a loop at some time-interval.

Comment: I see, thanks for the input. However, I am very confused on how I would do this, because in order to obtain the credentials, I need to be signed in/or sign in (as far as I am concerned). So how would I do this without asking for email and password every single time?

Comment: you need to save those credential(when user log in for first time) in userdefaults or persistent store.

Answer (score 1):

I reloaded the current User, if it's disabled you will get an error:

```
if let userInfo = Auth.auth().currentUser {
            userInfo.reload(completion: { (error) in
                guard error == nil else {
                    debugPrint(error.debugDescription)
                    return
                }
            })
}
```

Comment: Adding error code detection could be useful here, network error and user disabled should not be treated differently...
Interesting values would be
// error._code == 17020 user is offiline
// error._code == 17005 user account has been disabled by an administrator.
// error._code == 17011 Account Deleted

Answer (score 0):

Your asked a while ago, hope answer still helps:

You can add an observer for authStateDidChange, so it got fired if user logged out

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.AuthStateDidChange, object: Auth.auth(), queue: nil) { _ in

            if ((Auth.auth().currentUser) == nil) {
                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let mvc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainViewController")
                self.window!.rootViewController = mvc
                let options: UIView.AnimationOptions = .transitionCrossDissolve
                let duration: TimeInterval = 0.1
                UIView.transition(with: self.window!, duration: duration, options: options, animations: {}, completion:
                { completed in
                    self.window?.rootViewController?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showWelcomeView", sender: nil)
                })
            }
        }
```

The cool thing now is if you call the reload command, like MegaChan mentioned before, and the user got disabled or deleted, the firebase controller logs the user out, the observer fires authstate did change and your login screen, in my case welcomeviewcontroller shows up ;)